# org/springframework/boot/maven/BuildInfoMojo has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime

Tags: java, maven, mojo

i'm getting this error when i mvn clean install my project:

```
org/springframework/boot/maven/BuildInfoMojo has been compiled by a more recent 
version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java 
Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

i checked the used java version, it's then right one.

springBoot version: 2.1.2
java version: 1.8.0_121

any solution please ?

Comment: You have dependencies which require JDK17 (file verison 61) but you have JDK8... It looks like a mixup between spring boot versions because Spring Boot 3.X requires JDK17... but without your pom file it's hard to guess...

Comment: thank your your comment, yes it was related to springBoot version, i updated my springBoot from 2.6.6 to 2.1
the fix is specifying the Maven pluging build version in the pom

Comment: As others already wrote there are other issues in your pom but as mentioned earlier without the full pom it's impossible... even to guess..

Answer (score 0):

it was related to springBoot version, i updated my springBoot from 2.6.6 to 2.1 the fix is specifying the springBoot maven pluging version in the pom

Comment: That isn't the fix... The fact that you need to do this indicates you have actually other issues in your build file.